# Kotlin/Native: Is CValue<T>.useContents dangerous?

Tags: c, kotlin, memory-management, kotlin-native

In [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-c-interop.html#pass-and-receive-structs-by-value) paragraph it states that `useContents` "temporarily places the CValue to memory, and then runs the passed lambda with this placed value T as receiver".

A few questions about this:

1. Since this implies that `T` is not in memory at this moment, is there a risk that `useContents` fails because the value no longer available?
2. What happens if I do this: `val foo = bar.useContents { this }`. Does this copy `T`? Is it now in memory permanently? Do I need to clean it up manually somehow?
3. Why is this even necessary? Can't the compiler take care of these details? I just end up writing a lot of extension functions to hide `useContents`.